# Order of member variables initialization of the base class in the derived class (constructor)

Tags: c++, inheritance, initialization

Did I correctly understand how the initialization is working in here? I will illustrate the steps:

1. Base class constructor is called. We **output** `0` and increment `m_i = 1`;
2. since `m_x` is before `m_a` in the member variables of the base class and we are u pre incrementing `m_i`. We **output** `2` and we increment `m_i`.
3. we are creating an dynamic array of objects of type A. for `m_a[0]` we **output** `0` and we increment `m_i`; for m_a[1] we **output** `0` and we increment `m_i`. `m_i` for `m_a[0]` is equal to `1` and `m_i` for `m_a[1]` is equal to `1`.
4. finally we move to body of the constructor of the derived class and we **output** `m_i = 2.`

> the output is : 02002

i didn't really understand why the output of `m_i` is equal 2 when we get into the body of the base constructor? Shouldn't `m_i` be equal to `3` after step 2?

---

## source code

```
   #include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A(int n = 0)
        : m_i(n)
    {
        std::cout << m_i;
        ++m_i;
    }

protected:
     int m_i;
};

class B
    : public A
{
public:
    B(int n = 5) : m_a(new A[2]), m_x(++m_i){ std::cout << m_i; }

    ~B() { delete [] m_a;}

private:
    A m_x;
    A *m_a;
 
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: You seem to confuse something about inheritance vs containment.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ oh boy I am in a mess then

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Did you mean to track `static int m_i;`?

Comment: A little confusing may be the fact that members are initialized in the order in which they are listed in the class and not in the order listed in the initializer list of a constructor.

Comment: Here is a more verbose version so you can follow along with the debugger: http://ideone.com/JjCTxc

Comment: I think you are mixing up `b.m_i` with `b.a_x.m_i`

Comment: @M.M yes this is exactly what i didn't understand. But it's ok now. The answer was good;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I explain the problem, let me say this: if your object's initialization is so complex that it requires the detailed knowledge I'm about to relate, then fix *that*. Overcomplicating your initialization is to nobody's benefit.

Now, let's look at what happens when you construct an object of type `B` by calling its default constructor.

Since `B::A` is not mentioned in the member initializer list, it will be default initialized. That will call `A(int)` with its default value of 0. The result of this will be initializing `B::A::m_i` with the value 0, followed by outputing that value, followed by incrementing `B::A::m_i` to the value 1.

Now, we initialize the members of `B`. The first member to be initialized is `B::m_x`. The member initializer for this reads and increments the value of `B::A::m_i`, which is a validly initialized value that happens to be 1 before this operation. So before calling `A(int)` for `B::m_x`, `B::A::m_i` takes the value 2.

`B::m_x` is initialized via a call to `A(int)` with the value 2. It stores that value in `B::m_x.m_i`, outputs it, and increments it by one.

Next, we initialize `B::m_a`. The member initializer initializes it via a call to `new A[2]`, which will default construct 2 instances of `A`. These are all completely irrelevant to your question, as they are in no way related to `B::A::m_i`. But it does output two zeros.

After initializing `B::m_a`, we enter `B`'s default constructor itself.There, it simply outputs the value of `B::A::m_i`. Which if you recall, was last set to 2. So that's what it outputs.

Comment: thank you for the answer. After reading it a couple of times. It all seemed clear. the most important paragraph of the your answer is this: 

**Now, we initialize the members of B. The first member to be initialized is B::m_x. The member initializer for this reads and increments the value of B::A::m_i, which is a validly initialized value that happens to be 1 before this operation. So before calling A(int) for B::m_x, B::A::m_i takes the value 2.**